# parsing nested logic from strings in python

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, pyparsing

I need to turn a string of the form:

```
'a==1&&(b==2||(c==3||d==4&&e==5)&&f==6)||(g==7&&h==8)'
```

into sqlalchemy logic to be filtered (via `or_` and `and_`).  The first step is actually parsing the string into something useful.  I'd like to get it into the form:

```
['a==1','&&',['b==2','||',['c==3','||','d==4','&&','e==5'],'&&','f==6'],'||',['g==7','&&','h==8']]
```

and then step through recursively to parse it.  Unfortunately, I'm having trouble with this parsing step, having never used pyparsing before.

**EDIT (solution)**

I couldn't find a straightforward solution on `so` or on the interblag, but after quite a bit of digging through docs, I managed to put the following simple expression together:

```
from pyparsing import Word, alphanums, nestedExpr

content  = Word( alphanums + '=' ) | '||' | '&&'
unnester = nestedExpr( content = content )

a = 'a==3||b==1&&(c==4||(d==1||e==5)&&f==9)'
unnester.parseString( '(' + a + ')' ).asList()
```

As long as a flattening step is executed during iteration, this seems to work pretty well.

Answer (score 3):

I haven't really used `pyparsing` either, but here is a straight python implementation that will do what you want:

```
import re
from collections import namedtuple

TOKENIZER = re.compile(r"\w+==\w+|&&|\|\||[()]").findall

Node = namedtuple("Node", ["parent", "children"])

def syntax_tree(text, tokenizer, brackets):
    root = cur_node = Node(None, [])
    stack = []
    for token in tokenizer(text):
        if token == brackets["("]:
            stack.append(token)
            new_node = Node(cur_node, [])
            cur_node.children.append(new_node)
            cur_node = new_node
        elif token == brackets[")"]:
            if stack and stack.pop() == brackets[")"]:
                cur_node = cur_node.parent
            else:
                raise Exception("Parse error: unmatched parentheses")
        else:
            cur_node.children.append(token)

        if stack:
            raise Exception("Parse error: unmatched parentheses")

    return root

def listify(root):
    if isinstance(root, Node):
        return [listify(item) for item in root.children]
    else:
        return root


if __name__ == "__main__":
    expr = "a==1&&(b==2||(c==3||d==4&&e==5)&&f==6)||(g==7&&h==8)"

    tree = syntax_tree(expr, TOKENIZER, {"(": "(", ")": ")"})
    obj = listify(tree)
```

Comment: What's the purpose of `stack = []` ?

Comment: @BurhanKhalid: Looks like someone forgot to push and pop parenthesized expressions on and off the stack. :-)

Comment: Yes I have hoping to trigger an edit from Joel on that question :)

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Yes I originally had implemented a stack, but in order to simplify, I removed the check for parsing errors and thus the need for a stack in the first place. In retrospect, it's probably a good idea to do that, so I'll put it back :) See edit.

Comment: This is a really cool solution! I think your first nested if (`if stack and stack.pop() == brackets[')']`) needs to test for the opposite parenthesis to come from the stack

Comment: IMHO, While regular expressions can be nice for code that you are using for your own convenience they tend to be error prone and hard to read, so they clutter up production code.  This particular example is fairly straightforward, but it is easier to read a one-hundred line chained-together series of string functions than a ten-thousand character regex.

Answer (score 1):

Pyparsing has a builtin for parsing parenthetically grouped operations, including recognition of precedence of operators, called `infixNotation` (formerly named `operatorPrecedence`). See how it is used in this sample code to parse your example expression:

```
from pyparsing import Word, alphas, nums, oneOf, Group, infixNotation, opAssoc

sample = 'a==1&&(b==2||(c==3||d==4&&e==5)&&f==6)||(g==7&&h==8)'

# define some basic elements
varname = Word(alphas)
integer = Word(nums).setParseAction(lambda t:int(t[0]))

# Use varname and integer to define a comparison expression
comparisonOp = oneOf("< == > <= >= !=")
term = varname | integer
comparisonExpr = Group(term + comparisonOp + term)

# Use pyparsing builtin 'infixNotation' to implement parser for
# parenthetically grouped expression of various operators (formerly
# named 'operatorPrecedence')
logicalExpr = infixNotation(comparisonExpr,
    [
    ('&&', 2, opAssoc.LEFT),
    ('||', 2, opAssoc.LEFT),
    ])

# parse out your sample expression, use pprint to do some pretty-printing
import pprint
pprint.pprint(logicalExpr.parseString(sample).asList())
```

Prints:

```
[[[['a', '==', 1],
   '&&',
   [['b', '==', 2],
    '||',
    [[['c', '==', 3], '||', [['d', '==', 4], '&&', ['e', '==', 5]]],
     '&&',
     ['f', '==', 6]]]],
  '||',
  [['g', '==', 7], '&&', ['h', '==', 8]]]]
```

Comment: This is a *lot* more code than my edit and does not produce the desired output...